# How can I call ReactJS chunk files via sharepoint master page without webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online

I developed an application with ReactJS and got chunk files with `npm run build`. But how can I call these files via sharepoint master page. I just add the main chunk files to master page and loaded it but it  never called the component and it doesn't render.

I uploaded the below files to the SiteAssets folder in SharePoint. I just the call **main.553276c9.chunk.js** via master page.

- 0.45984e43.chunk.js
- 0.45984e43.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
- 0.45984e43.chunk.js.map
- 3.e5ccfe13.chunk.js
- 3.e5ccfe13.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
- 3.e5ccfe13.chunk.js.map
- 4.bdcd656e.chunk.js
- 4.bdcd656e.chunk.js.map
- 5.41ddc0b8.chunk.js
- 5.41ddc0b8.chunk.js.map
- 6.cc7d4939.chunk.js
- 6.cc7d4939.chunk.js.map
- main.553276c9.chunk.js
- main.553276c9.chunk.js.map
- runtime-main.85cbbfa2.js
- runtime-main.85cbbfa2.js.map

Comment: What tools are you using to build these files?

Comment: I am creating these files with react-scripts build so npm run build command line.

Answer (score 0):

Most build systems that generate files like this should also generate an `index.html` file that should load and run your app. You should upload that html file, along with all js files, and run your app from that.

If you're using Create React App with `react-scripts` the `index.html` should be in `build/index.html`.

[According the documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build) `runtime-main.85cbbfa2.js` is file to include.

> runtime-main.[hash].js
>
> - This is a small chunk of webpack runtime logic which is used to load and run your application. The contents of this will be embedded in your build/index.html file by default to save an additional network request. You can opt out of this by specifying INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false as documented in our advanced configuration, which will load this chunk instead of embedding it in your index.html.

Just note that that filename will change when the code changes.  The build process will update your HTML file, with that new filename. So you definately want to be in the habit of uploading that.

Comment: If i make webpack configuration manually this problem is solved with publicPath, but I want to use the default webpack configuration of reactjs, and I don't want to set up a webpack.